# Using Jackson ObjectMapper with Java 8 Optional values

Tags: java, jackson, java-8

I was trying to use Jackson to write a class value to JSON that has Optional as fields:

```
public class Test {
    Optional<String> field = Optional.of("hello, world!");

    public Optional<String> getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Test()));
    }
}
```

When executed, this class generates the following output:

```
{"field":{"present":true}}
```

I understand the present/not present field being included and could work around it when reading the JSON data, however I can't get around the fact that the actual content of the optional is never written to the output. :(

Any workarounds here except not using ObjectMapper at all?

Comment: Optionals are not meant to be used as fields (or properties for that matter). They should only be used as return values.

Comment: @zeroflagL could you please provide any credible sources describing what Optional is meant to be?

Comment: @Jonas [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327957/should-java-8-getters-return-optional-type/26328555#26328555) e.g.: _Our intention was to provide a limited mechanism for library method return types where there needed to be a clear way to represent "no result"_. Also not implementing `Serializable` is pretty self-evident.

Comment: Even when considering `Optional` only as a return type, we might still want to put the returned `Optional` in a JSON representation. e.g. you have a service returning the language for a given text. The service method call returns an `Optional` and that's what you want in your json.

Comment: [Using Optional with Jackson | Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-optional)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You could use [jackson-datatype-jdk8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jdk8) which is described as:

> Support for new JDK8-specific types, such as Optional

In order to do this:

- add `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8` as a dependency
- register the module with your object mapper: `objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());`

Comment: As per the linked GitHub repository:

`NOTE: This module has become part of Jackson Java 8 Modules as of Jackson 2.8.5

This repo still exists to allow release of patch versions of older versions; it will be hidden (made private) in near future.`

Comment: You also need to register a module like 



```ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());```

Answer (score 17):

Similar to @Manikandan's answer but add `@JsonProperty` to the private field instead of a getter so you don't expose your work around on the public api.

```
public class Test {

    @JsonProperty("field")
    private String field;

    @JsonIgnore
    public Optional<String> getField() {
        return Optional.of(field); // or Optional.ofNullable(field);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

The `Optional` class has a `value` field, but no standard getter/setter for it. By default, Jackson looks for getters/setters to find class properties.

You can add a custom Mixin to identify the field as a property

```
final class OptionalMixin {
    private Mixin(){}
    @JsonProperty
    private Object value;
}
```

and register it with your `ObjectMapper`.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixInAnnotations(Optional.class, OptionalMixin.class);
```

You can now serialize your object.

```
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Test()));
```

will print

```
{"field":{"value":"hello, world!","present":true}}
```

---

Consider also looking at [`jackson-datatype-guava`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson/jackson-datatype-guava). There's a Jackson `Module` implementation for Guava types including their `Optional`. It's possibly more complete than what I've shown above.

Comment: That works, thank you. Is there a way to make that Mixin a default for all new mappers?

Comment: @asieira I believe you'll need to register `Module` which registers the mixin. You have to then create the mapper with this `Module`. (I don't know if that suits you better than only registering the mixin.)

Answer (score 14):

You only need to register module `Jdk8Module`. Then it will serialize any `Optional<T>` as `T` if it is present or `null` otherwise.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
```

Let's modify `Test` class a bit so we can test for an `Optional.empty()` value. This is similar to the original `Test` class when serialized because the object mapper is looking for the getter (since the field is `private`). Using the original `Test` class will work too, though.

```
class Test {
    private final String field;

    public Test(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public Optional<String> getField() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(field);
    }
}
```

Then in our main class:

```
Test testFieldNull = new Test(null);
Test testFieldNotNull = new Test("foo");

// output: {"field":null}
System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(testFieldNull)); 

// output: {"field":"foo"}
System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(testFieldNotNull));
```

Answer (score 5):

Try passing in options into `@JsonInclude` annotation.
For example, if you don't want to show `field` when the value is `null`. *You might need to use Jackson-Modules >2.8.5*.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;

public class Test {
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    Optional<String> field;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly I was looking for and what probably should be the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Define new getter which will return String instead of Optional.

```
public class Test {
    Optional<String> field = Optional.of("hello, world!");

    @JsonIgnore
    public Optional<String> getField() {
        return field;
    }

    @JsonProperty("field")
    public String getFieldName() {
        return field.orElse(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: That would work, yes, but would defeat the purpose or returning an Optional value in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using latest version of Spring-boot then you could achieve this by adding the following dependency in the pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And auto wire the JacksonObjectMapper.

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper;
```

Then use the above Spring container's mapper instance to convert Object to String

```
jacksonObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(user);
```

[Spring blog says :](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring)

> Some well known Jackson modules are automatically registered if they are detected on the classpath:
>
> - jackson-datatype-jdk7: Java 7 types like java.nio.file.Path (as of 4.2.1 release)
> - jackson-datatype-joda: Joda-Time types
> - jackson-datatype-jsr310: Java 8 Date & Time API data types
> - jackson-datatype-jdk8: other Java 8 types like Optional (as of 4.2.0 release)