# Can I use java.util.Optional in Jersey application as a POJOs attribute?

Tags: java-8, jersey-2.0, option-type

Is there a way to use Java8's Optional in a Jersey application?

If you have a Pojo

```
public class Test {
    String id;
    Optional<String> message;

    // getters and setters 
}
```

Could I then use that Test class in a controller like so:

```
@POST
public Response save(Test test) {
    test.message.isPresent()...
    return Response.build();
}
```

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26328555/2587435) about your usage  of `Optional`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27271865/2587435) for Jackson solution

Comment: I was hoping there would be a solution _not_ using Jackson :)