# How to add Jdk8Module on ObjectMapper for Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I am using Jackson 2.9.6. I have a controller in which I am trying to send an Optional as one of my fields. When I receive a response from the controller I always get it in this format `{"field":{"present":true}}` (as shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693309/using-jackson-objectmapper-with-java-8-optional-values)).

Basically I have a RestTemplate bean configured as such:

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And I would like to add the Jdk8Module as part of the serialzation process. I noticed that there's a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(ObjectMapper mapper)` constructor which takes in an ObjectMapper and I'm thinking of creating an ObjectMapper bean which will have the Jdk8Module registered to it (using a public method called `registerModule(Module module)` found in the ObjectMapper class) so I can pass that module as such:

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <constructor-arg name="objectMapper" ref="ObjectMapperWithJDK8Bean"></constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="ObjectMapperWithJDK8Bean" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper">
* Pass in com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module here via the method *
</bean>
```

But the issue im current facing is how to call the `registModule` method from the xml file when creating the bean? I am using Spring 4.1. I'm new to Spring so this is pretty challenging!

Comment: According to [this](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring#jackson-modules) the jdk8 module should be registered automatically when found on the class path.

Comment: But it says that was added as of 4.2... I'm currently using 4.1 :/ I can't really upgrade to 4.2 right now

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that your code was so ancient ;(

Comment: Is this a legacy application you're maintaining?

Comment: @chrylis pretty much unfortunately

Comment: Ah. In that case, I would suggest moving the Jackson mapper bean into JavaConfig so that you can do this more easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a bean with java config instead of xml like :

```
@Configuration
public class GeneralConfiguration { 
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
           .registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
           .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
           .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

I believe that both the @Configuration and @Bean annotations are available since [spring 3.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) , so you could use them without any issues.
If you still wish to continue with xml based configuration then :

```
<bean id="objectMapper"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="modulesToInstall"
        value="
        com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module,
        com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule,
        com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paramnames.ParameterNamesModule" />
</bean>
```

Read [doc](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8)