# How to specify a JsonFormat for an Optional<LocalDate> using LocalDateSerializer?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class like this:

```
public class Foo {
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @JsonSerialize(contentUsing = LocalDateSerializer.class)
    private Optional<LocalDate> localDate;
}
```

I then serialize the class using an `ObjectMapper`, registering both `Jdk8Module` and `JavaTimeModule`.

However, I'm getting a JSON that I'm not expecting: For `LocalDate.of(2020, 4, 1)`, it gets serialized to the following: (code formatted for clarity)

```
{
    "localDate": [2020, 4, 1]
}
```

instead of:

```
{
    "localDate": "2020-04-01"
}
```

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802544/java-8-localdate-jackson-format

Comment: No, sorry. I need to use Optional.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693309/using-jackson-objectmapper-with-java-8-optional-values

Comment: No, sorry. That example doesn't use JsonFormat.

Comment: What version of Jackson do you use already?

Comment: The latest one: 2.11.0

Comment: That first link contained the answer, but the one I added as a duplicate is more explicit. You need to disable `WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS`.